# Centering two child Divs inside parent Div

Tags: html, css

I know this has been discussed in length, but I cannot seem to find an answer to solve this problem. This is a simple example to illustrate my issue. I have two children `div` elements inside a parent `div` and I want them to be horizontally centered inside the parent `div`. Here is the fiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8on1cko/4/)

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: solid blue 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

.tile {
    width: 20em;
    height: 40em;
    border:solid black 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1.5em auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <!--
   When you remove this comment, the div shifts down and I do not understand what is causing that.
    <h3>This Title Moves the div down. Why?</h3>-->
  </div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Now is there a simple solution that I am missing? Also, I have a secondary question about the `h3` tag as well. When the comment around the `h3` tag is removed, the first `div` shifts down. What about the `h3` tag is causing the `div` to shift down and how do I prevent it from happening?

Thanks for your answers and your help, and I apologize for a potential repeat question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below code to `#container`:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

**Live Snippet**

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: solid blue 1px;
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.tile {
    width: 20em;
    height: 40em;
    border:solid black 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <!--
   When you remove this comment, the div shifts down and I do not understand what is causing that.
    <h3>This Title Moves the div down. Why?</h3>-->
  </div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! That worked wonderfully! Can you briefly explain what that CSS is actually doing? I read another post that mentioned dispaly: flex but when I looked it up it seemed like that wasn't what I wanted. I guess I should have read about it in more depth. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Both `justify-content` and `align-items` define how browsers distribute space between elements, but `justify-content` controls the horizontal alignment while `align-items` controls the vertical one. For more info, check [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) from MDN.

Comment: So I have expanded on this example and added more `div`s inside the parent `div` and the children `div` elements stay on the same line and just reduce the width to fit inside the parent on the same line. I am assuming that is because the `flex` of the parent `div` is telling the children to be "flexible" to fit inside. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: That's about right. If you add `flex-wrap: wrap;` in `#container` css, it will be wrapped following the original `.tile` width. By default, browsers assign `flex-wrap: nowrap;`.

Comment: Check [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35) if you are interested in `flex`. It has a beautiful explanation. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I did some further reading on W3 schools about `flex` and I found the `flex-wrap` attribute to achieve what I wanted. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add: .title { display: block; }

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: solid blue 1px;
    width: 100%;
  
}

.tile {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  height: 40em;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  width: 20em;
  text-align:justify;
  padding:7px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tile">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have specified that I would like the child `div`s to be inline. Which is why I have inline-block listed as the display. I have read on other posts, that that could cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `margin:auto` to `.tile` and `text-align:center` to `#container`

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: solid blue 1px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.tile {
    width: 20em;
    height: 40em;
    border:solid black 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <h3>This Title Moves the div down. Why?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked as well as the comment below about display: flex. Can you explain why those bits of CSS worked to make this happen? I'm trying to better understand so as to avoid simple problems like this in the future.

Comment: `text-align` specifies horizontal alignment inside an element, so it puts inside of `#container` at center. so this works

Answer (score 0):

When you use `display:inline-block` by default was `vertical-align: bottom;` so that set css for `.tile` to `vertical-align: middle;` and `text-align:center` to `#container`

```
.tile {
    width: 20em;
    height: 40em;
    border:solid black 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1.5em auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Working Code: https://jsfiddle.net/e8on1cko/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
   ` `
```

```css
#container {
       padding:25%;
       text-align:center;
       background:#e7e7e7;
    }
    
.tile{
       background:white;
       display:inline-block;
       padding:20%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <h3>This Title Moves the div down. Why?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```